# The Nomenclature Of Poly substituted benzenes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

I am confused as to the nomenclature of poly substituted benzenes. Would more preference be give to to priority order or the alphabetical order? In [this](http://www.chem.ualberta.ca/~vederas/Chem_263/outlines/notes_2010/Chem263_Oct5_notes_2010.pdf) pdf, 4-aminophenol has been cited as more correct rather than 4- hydroxyaniline. However, there are some websites which site the other one as more correct. What would be the correct nomenclature. A reference from one of IUPAc's books itself would be great.

Thanks a lot!!